# ORA-01017: invalid username/password;logon denied

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, logins, password

There were other similar questions asked, but none that were able to tell me why I can't connect using a C# .NET web site I've stood up.  While I know this forum is more for DBAs connecting to databases using tools and not so much troubleshooting apps connecting, I thought I'd give it a shot posting the question here.

The web site works/connects from my workstation when ran from Visual Studio, but when I publish it to the server, it gives me the `ORA-01017:  invalid username/password;logon denied` error, even though I can connect via everything else with the same account/password. Situation:

1. I can connect using Oracle SQL Developer, SQL*Plus just fine with the account I'm using... let's call it "myaccount".
2. Using Net Manager, I can expand "Service Naming" and see the entries from my tnsnames.ora.
   a. The same string that exists in tnsnames.ora/Service Naming area, exists as a hard-coded string in my application, with the exception of things like the host name, service name, port, user name, and password, which are passed-in as parameters from my web.config.
   b. I can click a connection name and everything appears correctly, and clicking "Test Service" > "Change Login" > enter "myaccount" and password > click OK > click "Test" succeeds.
   c. I have double-checked my parameters in my web.config - nothing has changed since the web site ran on my local workstation.
3. `tnsping CONNECTION_NAME` succeeds.
4. Environmental variables are the same on both computers, as are the Oracle client locations.
   a. `ORACLE_HOME` = `C:\oracle\product\12`
   b. `PATH` = `C:\oracle\product\12\bin;` .....
   c. `TNS_ADMIN` = `C:\oracle\product\12\network\admin`
   d. Registry entry added to `HKLM\Software\Oracle\KEY_OraClient12Home` for `TNS_ADMIN` = `C:\oracle\product\12\network\admin`
5. I've tried the `ALTER SYSTEM SET SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = FALSE;` command and reset the password, just in case that was the issue. I tried connecting with all-caps versions of myaccount and its password, as well as all lower-case versions of both (lower-case on both is how I had it originally when it worked on my workstation).
6. The account has a `PASSWORD_VERSIONS` of `10G` and `11G` - I don't know if it matters that I'm using a 12c client and `12C` is not there. Main difference between the server and my workstation is I only have the 12c client on the server - I have 10g, 11g, and 12c on my workstation. I was going to try using the 11g ODP.NET assembly, `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`, but my code won't compile (I get `"Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.".`), even after changing the namespace from `using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` to `using Oracle.DataAccess.Client`.
7. Attempted passing in the password with quotes around it and without--both methods worked on my Visual Studio instance, just not on the server.
8. If I deliberately put in a totally bogus password, and run the site on the server enough times, it will lock the account, so I know it's connecting to the database.

Running out of things to try... any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have seen this only once so far, but there is an issue described in the My Oracle Suppport note:

**FIPS use causes ORA-01017: Invalid Username/password with Managed ODP.NET (Doc ID 1937500.1)**

I will not post the full content of this as it is not public, but here is the essence:

> This bug has been fixed in 12.1.0.2 Managed Provider. Please note that the DB version must be 12.1.0.2 or higher for this fix to work as expected.
>
> The workaround is to set in the registry
>   `System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FIPSAlgorithmPolicy\Enabled` to
>   `0`.

Some public references to this matter:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410951/oracle-manageddataaccess-and-ora-01017-invalid-username-password-logon-denied

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31785650/ora-01005-error-connecting-with-odp-net

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2557592?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

I was trying with the command:

ALTER SYSTEM SET SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = FALSE;

But it didn't work. 
I had to change it using the SQL Developer in the DBA tab.

1. Find the Parameter 'sec_case_sensitive_logon' and change its value to 'FALSE'
   [image]
2. Commit your changes using the button: 
   [image]
3. It will ask the commit strategy and you have to choose both:
   [image]
4. Click 'Apply'
5. I don't know if this step is required, but I also changed the user's password. (I set the same password)

In case, you don't know how to open the 'Initialization Parameters':

1. Open 'Oracle SQL Developer'
2. Go to 'View' menu and select 'DBA'
3. Choose a connection
4. And then click on 'Initialization Parameters'

[image]